# Access a custom attribute's binding from another custom attribute

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Say I have an Aurelia Custom Attribute that I am working with, is it possible to fire an event when a value bound to another Custom Attribute changes?

To put it in more concrete terms, I am building an Aurelia Custom Attribute for Chosen.  I got all of Chosen working.

But the `<select>` element has a `focus.bind="isFocused"` on it.  I need to know (in my Chosen Custom Attribute) when that bound value changes.

**Is there some way to access that focus binding (from the focus Custom Attribute) in my Chosen Custom Attribute?**  Maybe using the binding engine or even an internal method?

(NOTE: I considered making a custom element to do this, but Aurelia does not work well for wrapping elements.  I would have to code up connections for styles, classes and anything else that is on the original select component.)

Comment: Perhaps you can use the binding behavior `signal`: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors/5 Just a first thought

Comment: @marc I looked into that extensively. It will not work for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is right way of doing this, but it's the easiest way I've found so far.

**my-attr.js**

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Focus } from 'aurelia-templating-resources';

@inject(Focus)
export class MyAttrCustomAttribute {

  constructor(focusAttr) {
    this.focusAttr = focusAttr;
  }

  attached() {
    console.log(this.focusAttr.value); //bound value

    //...
    //extending the change event. BE CAREFUL!
    //...

    const originalValueChanged = this.focusAttr.valueChanged;
    this.focusAttr.valueChanged = function(newValue) {
      console.log('Focus bound value has changed!'); //<-- call an event before "focus"
      originalValueChanged.call(this, newValue); //<-- "focus" is enqueued
      // <--- enqueue an event event here to be called after "focus"
    }

  }
}
```

Running example https://gist.run/?id=ab04facb60b39f9c6a5fc49c2fd278a6

Answer (score 0):

Try using a binding behavior to intercept the binding's `updateSource` (update the view model) and `updateTarget` (update the view) methods. There's a running example of this in the docs under the *Custom binding behaviors* section.

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors/8

Comment: What if the second binding is optional?